# Virtual destructor - when it is necessary

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have a base class X with only one virtual function.

I extend it to Y and override that function.

I didn't provide explicit destructor for X and Y.

What happens during the destruction in this statement.

```
Y y;
X *x= &y;
return;
.
.
.
X*x = new Y;
delete x;
return;
```

Which will cause memory leak..

Comment: Neither? Also I don't see how these two code snippets on their own are related to virtual destructors? You'd need to at least show the class definitions.

Comment: 1) No problem. x is just a pointer, but y gets destructed and frees all resources from super class too. 2) Resources of Y get lost, because just the destructor of X is called on an instance of Y in memory -> possible memory leak (or worse).

Comment: @UnholySheep there is nothing special about class definition. I mentioned the statement. The second one seems to cause a memory leak

Answer (score 0):

```
Y y;
X *x = &y;
return;
```

Nothing bad happens here.  The object `y` is (fully) destroyed at the end of its scope.

```
X*x = new Y;
delete x;
return;
```

This will cause a memory leak *if you're lucky*.  The behavior is undefined, meaning anything bad could happen.

It's generally a good idea to declare a virtual destructor whenever the class is intended to be a base class for other classes.